# Codename one expect feature on DateTime Component

Tags: codenameone

Our client expects the feature like DateTime Component editable on double topping the Dates or Time or AM/PM instead of scrolling more.

We see that feature on some apps, Can't we get his feature in Codename one. Which is very helpful and will make codename one powerful tool.

Here is a screenshot of what we expect from DateTime picker.
[image]

Is there a way to achieve this on Andriod and IOS platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work as I'm not much of an Android guy but I made a change to the Android implementation that should allow the keyboard to open if you do:

```
myPicker.putClientProperty("showKeyboard", Boolean.TRUE);
```

This should start working following October 29th 2016 with the next update but since I didn't test it this might not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your support. We will wait for this feature for both android and iOS platforms.

Comment: That's not a feature of iOS. The picker component is a native component so it can't implement things that aren't available in the OS.